# How to click on button type "submit" using Selenium and C#

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Code trials:

```
chrome[row_index].FindElementByXPath("//*[@id=\"app\"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/button").Submit();
```

and

```
chrome[row_index].FindElementByXPath("//*[@id=\"app\"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/button").Click();
```

This is Error Message:

```
An exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException' occurred in WebDriver.dll but was not handled in user code element click intercepted: Element <button data-v-7b27a432="" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm form-control mt-3">...</button> is not clickable at point (464, 863). Other element would receive the click: <i data-v-5e808f53="" class="font-20 d-block mb-1 icon-question"></i>
```

This is Html Code Of Button :

```
<button data-v-7b27a432="" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm form-control mt-3">Tiếp Tục</button> .
```

It ready find that elment but cant click or cant submit that button

Comment: Use `element.Submit();` method

Comment: @LộcNguyễnTấn I have added the closing triangular brace to make the node a valid node. Let me know if the change looks good.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below solution :

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Tiếp Tục')]"));

Actions action = new Actions(Driver);
action.MoveToElement(element).Perform();
action.Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

The click on the element so you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *ElementToBeClickable* and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) as solutions:

- Using *CssSelector* and `Submit()`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("button.btn.btn-primary.btn-sm.form-control[type='submit']"))).Submit();
  ```
- Using *XPath* and `Click()`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//button[contains(@class, 'form-control') and text()='Tiếp Tục']"))).Click();
  ```